# PHP sending mail is not working and index of value is unreachable

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I used to post and action method to send mail. I tried to send short mail from hosting server by running test PHP. It was working. After merging it with HTML form is not working and also giving error undefined index. Here is the summary of the code. 
**HTML file:**

```
     <form id="msform" action="./php/mailer.php" name="step1"  method="POST">      
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Fillup basic Information</h2>
        <h3 class="fs=subtitle">This is step 1</h3><br>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required/>
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
 <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button"  value="Next" onclick="return validateStep1()"/>
     </fieldset>
    </from>
```

**PHP file:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['next']))
{
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];


  $msg="Hello My Name is $fname $lname . My Company is $company which is located in $address1 . The Second address is $address2. I live in $city city, $state state, $zip zip, $country.
  My Phone number is $tel. My Fax number is $fax. My email is $email. I want to donate $other. My Custom Donate is $otherDonation. I want to donate regular=$regulardonate for $dollar dollar
  per $months";

  mail("x@gmail.com","Donation",$msg);
}
?>
```

**JS File:**

```
function validateStep1()
{
  var fname =document.forms["step1"]["fname"];
  var lname =document.forms["step1"]["lname"];
if (fname.value == "")                                  
  { 
      window.alert("Please enter your first name."); 
      fname.focus();
      return false; 
  } 

  if (lname.value == "")                                  
  { 
      window.alert("Please enter your Last name."); 
      lname.focus(); 
      return false; 
  } 
    window.open('./second.html', '_self');
  return true;   
}
```

My Live form on GitHub, you check - https://tamzid958.github.io/multipage_form/

Comment: Where is the "undefined index" beeing thrown?

Comment: right now the PHP file is not triggering. but if I  run the script in the HTML file or if I use window.open('php.file') in JS file. a mail is sending with undefined index error. Name is not capturing right now. The PHP file is not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP file in your form is not working as https://tamzid958.github.io/multipage_form/ as a hosting is not parsing PHP at all. This hosting is only for static pages, like HTML, JS, CSS.

You need to put your code on a hosting that supports PHP..

Comment: I tried in 000webhosting. still same -
https://tamzid958.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: It is not the same. Try enabling error_reporting at the top of your PHP, and try debugging now.. You need to either see an actual error, or you need to add in your code some response which will for example echo out if error or success? You do not seem to be doing any debugging..

Comment: After Trying email is coming but $fname $lname is not capturing.

https://ibb.co/JcvXDBY

Comment: well, is `$_POST['next']` populated? If it is not, then `fname`,`lname` will be NULLed. You could update your question with all of the information, so we do not keep guessing.. :)